# Jquery How to load flexslider with two slider and slide at the same time?

Tags: jquery, flexslider

Jquery How to load flexslider with two slider and slide at the same time?
Jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          $(window).load(function(){
            $('#banner').css("visibility", "visible");
            $('#banner').flexslider({
              animation: "fade",
              pauseOnHover: true,
              controlNav: false, 
              slideshowSpeed: 3000,   
              directionNav: false,
              slideshow: true
            });
            $('#tag').css("visibility", "visible");
            $('#tag').flexslider({
              animation: "fade",
              pauseOnHover: true,
              controlNav: false, 
              slideshowSpeed: 3000,   
              directionNav: false,
              slideshow: true
            });
          });
        </script>
```

MY HTML

```
<div id="banner">
     <ul class="slides">
       <li><img src="assets/images/banner.jpg" alt=""></li>
       <li><img src="assets/images/banner2.jpg" alt=""></li>
       <li><img src="assets/images/banner3.jpg" alt=""></li>
       <li><img src="assets/images/banner4.jpg" alt=""></li>
     </ul>
       </div>
<div id="tag">
    <ul class="slides">
      <li><img src="assets/images/big_image.jpg" alt="" ></li>
      <li><img src="assets/images/big_image2.jpg" alt=""></li>
      <li><img src="assets/images/big_image3.jpg" alt=""></li>
      <li><img src="assets/images/big_image4.jpg" alt=""></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

they not slide at the same time even they have same slideshowSpeed.

Comment: Seems to be fine here http://jsfiddle.net/zczpD/

Comment: How the hell that's happen. Thanks mate.